# ListView items gone off screen

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, listview, kotlin

[image: ListView in XML]
[image: The row cut off when the program runs]
[image: My ListView Adapter]
[image: The row layout]

The problem is when I run the program the view cuts like what shown in the picture above
I don't know what the exact sort of problem, so if you need anything to show just ask 
I am using kotlin by the way

EDIT 1:
result_row.xml this is the XML for the row that shows in the ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemName"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/lineView2"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#010101" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemWeight"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Item Weight"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/lineView1"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#010101" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemPrice"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Do not use fixed width height

Comment: Can you share your result_row.xml?

Comment: "Can you share your result_row.xml?"  sure

Comment: "Do not use fixed width height " I tried that but still some of it goes off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TextView`s have fixed widths that total greater than the width of the screen:

```
android:layout_width="200dp"
...
android:layout_width="100dp"
...
android:layout_width="100dp"
```

Android phones can be as narrow as `320dp`, so it'll get cut off.  You need to modify your layout to use the available space, not hardcode fixed widths.  Or, if you really want to use fixed widths, they need to be smaller (shouldn't add up to more than `320dp`).

Comment: ill try it now and see whats happens

Comment: still, there is litters went off-screen but it is better than before at least... ill mark it as solved thx

Answer (score 0):

in your layout xml file edit

```
layout_width="0dp"
layoyt_height="0dp"
```

Comment: Still, some of words went off-screen